# Get last row of data in a While loop while reading CSV - Java

Tags: java, csv, while-loop

I am trying to read the last row of data in a CSV file when iterating through the entire file in a ***While loop***. I can manage to read and parse fine I just cant seem to figure out how to stop in the last row. I do not want to hardcode how many iterations to take.

Code:

```
File inputF = new File("T.csv");
InputStream getStream = new FileInputStream(inputF);
         
boolean flag = false;
            
            
    try {
        System.out.println("Checking Values of CSV...");
        if (getStream.read() != -1) {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getStream));
            String line;
            String headerLine;
            int counter = 0;
            headerLine = reader.readLine();
            
            //change condition to end at last row
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
               // logic to read and parse
                        
            }
            System.out.println(line);
            reader.close();
                    
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Output:

```
null
```

Expected Output(not accurate, actual data will be csv output):

```
CSV DATA
```

Recap -

I want to set a condition in the while loop so it stops in the last row so I can manage it. I cannot hardcode it because  amount of rows will change based on file reading..

Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: BufferedReader#readLine() will return null when the stream is empty. You can't know the last line, unfortunately. You could, however, put each line into an ArrayList<String> and then deal with them after you have read them all. Or you could deal with each line inside the while-loop.

Answer (score 1):

I think something like that will do the job. You just need to store the last lane you read successfully (what i'm doing with `line`) and when you can't read the next one (reading in `nextLine`), you're done !

```
InputStream getStream = new FileInputStream(inputF);
         
boolean flag = false;
            
            
    try {
        System.out.println("Checking Values of CSV...");
        if (getStream.read() != -1) {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getStream));
            String line;
            String nextLine;
            String headerLine;
            int counter = 0;
            headerLine = reader.readLine();
            
            //change condition to end at last row
            while ((nextLine= reader.readLine()) != null) {
               line = nextLine;
               // logic to read and parse
                        
            }
            System.out.println(line);
            reader.close();
                    
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I understood that you want to stop on the last line while you’re *inside* the loop. This can be done like shown below. If you just want to get the last line, the below code would also work.

```
        String headerLine;
        String footerLine;
        headerLine = reader.readLine();
        do {
            String line = reader.readLine();
            if (line == null) {
                // do something with footerLine
                break;
            }
        
           // logic to read and parse
           footerLine = line;
        } while (true);

        System.out.println(footerLine);
        // footerLine is the last line by now
        reader.close();
```